# Extract name from multiline mangled text string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using `importhtml()` to read data from a website and end up with a value like this in cell A1:

```
1
JorgeJ SolerSoler
DH
1
```

How do I extract the name "Jorge Soler" from this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a formula like this:

```
=regexextract(A1, "[A-Z][a-z]+") & regexextract(A1, "( [A-Z][a-z]+)[^ ]*?$")
```

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). These sites may also help:

- https://regexone.com/
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html
- https://regex101.com/